# Why not use Cookies for Authentication instead of sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, cookies, session

I would like to persist the user authentication between user sessions (basically a "remind me" by default).

Sessions expire while cookies persist: why should I use a session for authentication and then another different cookie for the "remind me"?

Can't I simply store a cookie whith a token and use it for both authentication and persistence?

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is because cookies can be changed by the user so it's not very secure. persistence doesn't always need to be secure but usually authentication needs to be.